# injecting different implementation of service bean in same controller from different servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to annotation based controller. I have two servlet like this:

pathA-servlet for url: pathA/*
pathB-servlet for url: pathB/*

And I have a controller like:

```
public class MyController extends SimpleFormController {

   private MyService myService;
```

}

And two service implementation:

```
public class MyService1 implements MyService {
}

public class MyService2 implements MyService {
}
```

And in pathA-servlet:

```
<bean name="/doSomeThing" class="MyController">
   <property name="myService" ref="myService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myService" class="MyService1"/>
```

And in pathB-servlet:

```
<bean name="/doSomeThing" class="MyController">
   <property name="myService" ref="myService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myService" class="MyService2"/>
```

Now, I am trying to do the same with annotation based controller using: @Controller, @RequestMapping. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would it be any different? Just make sure that there is just one instance of the `MyService` in either servlet and use `@Autowired` or just inject it like you did now. The fact that you use `@Controller` doesn't mean you cannot use the xml configuration anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample @Controller. This is a rest endpoint, you can access it with

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/my")
public class CopyOfMyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/hib")
    public void haha(@ResponseBody RequestDTO dto) {
        service.doSomething(dto);
    }

}
```

you can hit it with

```
Dto dto = new Dto();
dto.setPhone("12313");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.postForObject(new URI("http://localhost:8080/my/hib"), dto, Dto.class);
```

Comment: I was asking how can I inject two different implementation of service in the same controller from two different servlet using \@Controller and \@RequestMapping. That could be done in SimpleFormController but how do I do that in annotation based Controller?? @stackdev

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. In your controller, first add the `@Controller` annotation. This annotation simply says that this class will be a Spring controller that will be able to handle HTTP Requests based on the url mapping defined in the methods of your controller.

Also add an `@Autowired` annotation for the service attribute. Since there is 2 implementations of `MyService`, add the `@Qualifier` by passing the bean name because Spring would unable to choose which bean to inject otherwise.

So you can do something like this :

```
 @Controller
 public class MyController {

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("bean1") // This should be bean1
     private MyService myService1; 

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("bean2")
     private MyService myService2;  

     @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomeThing1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String doSomething(){
        return myService1.doSomething();
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomeThing2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String doSomething(){
        return myService2.doSomething();
     }
}
```